# Total memory usage by pg_activity

Tags: postgresql

Could anyone explains to me what is the MEM%, displayed by pg_activity?

I would like to know if MEM% represents \postgres total memory usage\, or 'the system memory usage'.

Thanks,

Comment: 1) compare it ti what top says 2) check the source code. (my guess is it uses the /proc interface, and reports the RSS / totalmem)

Comment: Why don't you ask at the github page by opening an issue?